# Using both setTimeout and setInterval possible?

Tags: jquery, animation, timer

How can I delay the execution of an animation that is composed of 30 sequences with an interval of 50ms?

```
$(function() {
    setInterval("anim1()", 50);
    setTimeout("anim1()", 3000); /* doesn't work */
});



function anim1() {
    var oCurBack = $('#fullback div.current');
    var oNxtBack = oCurBack.next();
    if (oNxtBack.length === 0)
        return;

    oNxtBack.addClass('current');
    oCurBack.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to have happen here.

Comment: Clear as glass to me ;)

Comment: Separately and only tangentially, look into `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: BTW, it looks obvious than you have to clear the interval at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumption: You want to start the interval animation after 3 seconds

- put the interval into a function you delay
- I use the `anim1` instead of `"anim1()"` since using the string is a hidden eval
- you likely want to stop the animation where you return now

---

```
var tId; // have global id to store the interval 
$(function() {
  tId = setTimeout(function() { setInterval(anim1, 50) }, 3000); 
})

function anim1() {
  var oCurBack = $('#fullback div.current');
  var oNxtBack = oCurBack.next();
  if (oNxtBack.length === 0) {
     clearInterval(tId); // clear the interval now we are done
     return;
  }
  oNxtBack.addClass('current');
  oCurBack.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
}
```

To repeat the animation every 4 secs try

```
var tId1, tId2
$(function() {
  tId1 = setInterval(function() { 
    var $divs = $('#fullback div.current');
    $divs.removeClass(current); // remove all current
    $divs.eq(0).removeClass('previous').addClass('current'); // add on the first
    tId2 = setInterval(anim1, 50); 
  }, 3000); 
});


function anim1() {
  var oCurBack = $('#fullback div.current');
  var oNxtBack = oCurBack.next();
  if (oNxtBack.length === 0) {
     clearInterval(tId2); // clear the interval now we are done
     return;
  }
  oNxtBack.addClass('current');
  oCurBack.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
}
```

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have downvoted it. I think the question's too unclear to answer presently, but that doesn't mean this answer is necessarily wrong.

Comment: But just answering as of *good luck* is not a good idea too. ;)

Comment: Well, for one thing, you might explain why you're not using strings.

Comment: Could be done bit shorter too: `setTimeout(setInterval, 3000, anim1, 50);`.

Comment: Do you think? I found it pretty easy. Function, Delay, Parameters. Not hard to tell. But it's subjectively. :)

Comment: It is counter intuitive to me that anim1 will be passed to setInterval - I like it but find it hard to grok

Comment: Thanks mplungjan & eisbehr! setTimeout(setInterval, 3000, anim1, 50); works fine. What if I want the anim1 function to play every 3 or 4 sec?

Comment: Change timeout to interval

Comment: I tried setInterval(setInterval, 4000, anim1, 50); and doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at my update. Here you need more code than the short version

Comment: @eisbehr how to clear the interval timeout in your syntax?

Comment: It doesn't repeat because .current is on my last image and the if statement stops it I think

Comment: did you see I set the current to the first div in the interval?

Comment: I see now, but .current stays stuck at my 30th image

Comment: Thank you so much I spent 2 days on that (and learned a lot of course)